# Matplotlib box plots - plotting grouped values with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot **box plots grouped by unique column values using a for loop** without knowing the number of unique values in that column.

You can see sample code below (without a for loop) and the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#------------------------------ Preparing the data frame -------------------------------#

df = pd.DataFrame(data = random.randn(5,4), index = ['A','B','C','D','E'],
columns = ['W','X','Y','Z'])

df['W'] = ['10/01/2018 12:00:00','10/03/2018 13:00:00',
           '10/03/2018 12:30:00','10/04/2018 12:05:00',
           '10/08/2018 12:00:15']

df['W']=pd.to_datetime(df['W'])

df['Entity'] = ['C201','C201','C201','C202','C202']
print(df)

#-----------------------------------Plotting the data ----------------------------------#

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data_to_plot = [df['Y'][df['Entity']=='C201'], df['Y'][df['Entity']=='C202']]

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot, showfliers=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(['C201' ,'C202'])      
plt.show()
```

**Desired output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
#-----------------------------------Plotting the data ----------------------------------#

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data_to_plot = []
tick_labels = []
for entity in df['Entity'].unique():
    data_to_plot.append(df['Y'][df['Entity']==entity])
    tick_labels.append(entity)

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot, showfliers=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)      
plt.show()
```